# Discord bot look for message from user

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

I am making a verification bot and the staff members have to accept or deny the user once the verification is sent with a reaction to the message. But if a staff member denies a user, The bot will ask for a reason which will be sent to the user. The issue is that when the bot is waiting for the staff member to send the reason if a message is sent in any other channel then the bot will use that message as the reason.

```py
        elif str(reaction) == "❌":
            remove_id(member.id)
            await verif_channel.send(":warning: Please provide a reason :warning:")
            try:
                deny_channel = member.guild.get_channel(889690902359080970)
                msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", timeout=600)
                why = msg.content
                embed_reason = discord.Embed(
                    title=":warning: You have been denied! :warning:",
                    description="You have been denied from the server for the following reason: (You are still allowed to reverify by reacting to the message in <#734570330064028002>) \n\n"
                    "{}".format(f"Reason: {why}"),
                    color=int(hex_color, 16))
                await member.send(embed=embed_reason)
                await verif_channel.send(f"❌ I have denied {member.mention}")

                embed2 = discord.Embed(
                    title="Verification Request",
                    description=f"Verification request of {member.mention}",
                    color=int(hex_color, 16)
                )
                embed2.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
                embed2.add_field(name="How did you find this server?", value=found, inline=False)
                embed2.add_field(name="How old are you?", value=age, inline=False)
                embed2.add_field(name="This is a server related question", value=about, inline=False)
                embed2.add_field(name="What are you looking to get out of this server?", value=seek, inline=False)
                embed2.add_field(name="User was:", value=f"Denied for {why}", inline=False)
                embed2.set_author(name=member.name)
                embed2.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {member.id}")

                channel = member.guild.get_channel(863099566672707594)

                await channel.purge(limit=4)
                await deny_channel.send(embed=embed2)

            except discord.Forbidden:
                await verif_channel.send(f"❌ Denied {member.mention}\n"
                                         f"User has blocked DMs")
```

I am trying to change it so that the bot will look for a message in the channel from the user that reacted to the message. I tried a few different ways but I don't really know how I would get the id of the user that reacted to the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to check if a message has been sent by a specific person is to use a `check function`. Please view the code below.

```py
# Define the check function within your code
def check(msg):
    return msg.author == reaction.author and not msg.author.bot
    # This checks if the author of the message is the author of the ❌ reaction
    # AND checks if the message author is a bot or not

msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=600)
```

Helpful link(s):

- [`client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) - discord.py docs